# How to add JwT token in request header ASP.Net MVC Core 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have just started to use Asp.Net Core and I managed to create a mvc project. In This project I have created an API and it is secured with token based authorization.**I have also used identity framework for user auhentication**. Now I want to consume this API to perform CRUD operations with passing token but have no clear idea how to do that. After searching similar questions what I have tried is generate the token using user credentials (username, password) when user successfully logged in or registered and attach the generated token to header and as far as I know it will be passed through each subsequent request.

First I tried creating a method to call to generate the token after success login or registration. This includes in same controller which used for login and registration.

**Token generate method**

```
public string GenerateAuthToken(ApplicationUser applicationUser)
{
  var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
  var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("JWT")["TokenSignInKey"]);
  var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
  {
     Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                 new Claim(type:JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, applicationUser.Id),
                 new Claim(type:JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, applicationUser.Email),
                 new Claim(type:JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, 
                        value:DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString())
               }),
     Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
     SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), 
                          SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
  };

  var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
  var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

  return stringToken;
}
```

I call this after success user login and register,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = registerViewModel.Username, 
                      Email = registerViewModel.Email};

       var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerViewModel.Password);

       if (result.Succeeded)
       {
           await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
           var token = GenerateAuthToken(user);

           var httpClient = new HttpClient();
           httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
                                             AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
       }

       ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Registration Failed");
   }

   return View(registerViewModel);
```

}
When this executed, the token is successfully generated but does not attach the token. I do not know if I am doing any wrong here. But I found someone facing the same issue but has tried different way to achieve this. I think it is the correct way but not sure. Instead of generate the token on success login, have to generate it each api call. According to [this solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/760827/how-to-add-bearer-token-to-a-request-in-aspnet-cor.html) I created another controller and action to generate the token.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken([FromBody] AuthViewModel authViewModel)
{
   var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == authViewModel.Email);
   if (user != null)
   {
      var signInResult = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, 
                               authViewModel.Password, false);
      if (signInResult.Succeeded)
      {
          var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
          var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("JWT") 
                    ["TokenSignInKey"]);
          var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
          {
              Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                        new Claim(type:JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,authViewModel.Email),
                        new Claim(type:JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, 
                                  authViewModel.Email),
                        new Claim(type:JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, 
                                  value:DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString())
              }),
              Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new 
                                               SymmetricSecurityKey(key), 
                                               SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
          };

          var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
          var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

          return Ok(new { Token = stringToken });
     }
     return BadRequest("Invalid User");
  }}
```

**AuthViewModel**

```
public class AuthViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I added authViewModel to accept logged user credentials since I don't want add them manually, Then I have created another controller to perform the CRUD **same as the above mentioned link** Please note that I followed the solution mentioned below that page.

```
private async Task<string> CreateToken()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:7015/Auth");
    request.Content = JsonContent.Create(new AuthViewModel{
                                 Email = user.Email, Password = user.PasswordHash
                                });

    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("JwToken", token);
    return token;

}
```

**request.Content** I added to match my solution since token should be generated using user credentials. But I have no idea how to pass the logged in user's credentials with the request. This does not work. It is not possible to access the user password.

This is how I called the token generate action to perform CRUD. And I use JQuery Ajax to call the GetAllSales endpoint.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllSales()
{
    string token = null;
    var strToken = HttpContext.Session.GetString("JwToken");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strToken))
    {
        token = await CreateToken();
    }
    else
    {
        token = strToken;
    }

    List<Sale> sales = new List<Sale>();
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 
                                         "http://localhost:7015/api/Sales");
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, 
                                          HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        sales = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sale>>(apiString);
    }
    Ok(sales);
}
```

This does not work. An exception throws
**'System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory' while attempting to activate '_7_ElevenRetail.Controllers.AccessApiController'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)'**

Please suggest me and show me how to achieve this correctly. I am expecting all of your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory' while attempting to activate '_7_ElevenRetail.Controllers.AccessApiController'

This issue means you inject `IHttpClientFactory` in AccessApiController without registering the service in `Program.cs`.

Register `IHttpClientFactory` by calling `AddHttpClient` in `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what you showed is one of my mistakes. I have added your configurations. But I could not achieve what I wanted. Since the user is already logged in I can not access their password. So I changed the logic to generate token only if the user is logged in and getToken function will not validate user credentials and only generate the token. However this also works because you showed me the missing configuration. So I will mark this as an accepted answer. Thank you very much.